# Updating a row in an Access database using OleDb, SQL and VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I know that there have been many questions on this topic however I cannot find any solutions for my problem. The code that I have created allows the user to create an account (which works perfectly) and right now I am trying to allow the user to change their username and/or password using textboxes. The code reads the details from the database and places them in textboxes to be changed and updated.  At the moment, I have managed to get the correct row and locate the correct fields but instead of replacing the current value with the value in the textbox (which I want), -1 or 0 is being placed in to the database in the username column and when I try to change the password, it does not change. The code is below:

```
 connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\RevisionAid2\RevisionAid2\UserDatabase.accdb"
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connstring)

    Dim updateSql As String = String.Format("UPDATE Users SET Username=@USER and [Password]=@PASS WHERE StudentID=@ID")

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(updateSql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", ChangeUsernameTextBox.Text.Trim) 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASS", ChangePasswordTextBox.Text.Trim)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", StudentID.Text)
    'conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

I have tested the SQL statement in Access and the correct value is returned and the update occurs so I don't know what could be causing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your updateSql even run?

The query should look like this:

```
UPDATE Users SET Username=@USER, [Password]=@PASS WHERE StudentID=@ID
```

And why do you trim username and password?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have placed it in an if statement so that if the user presses Yes in the messagebox then the query runs. My query is exactly like that but I read somewhere the password was a reserved word and that I'd need to put it in [], so I did, not sure if this is right. And I'm not too sure, I'm relatively new to programming and thought it'd help

Comment: Ok, yeah that's maybe true but you should swap "and" to ",".

Comment: Such a small change has fixed the problem. Thanks, I can't believe that stumped me for so long.

Comment: You're welcome, strange that your query even ran with that error.